# pip3 didn't work

Tags: python3, pip

When I try to install a package using pip3 (pip3 install tensorflow) I get this message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/__init__.py", line 33, in vendored
    __import__(vendored_name, globals(), locals(), level=0)
ImportError: No module named 'pip._vendor.pkg_resources'
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip3", line 9, in <module>
    from pip import main
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from pip.exceptions import InstallationError, CommandError, PipError
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/exceptions.py", line 6, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.six import iteritems
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/__init__.py", line 75, in <module>
    vendored("pkg_resources")
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/__init__.py", line 36, in vendored
    __import__(modulename, globals(), locals(), level=0)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 634, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources-0.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2927, in <module>
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources-0.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2913, in _call_aside
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources-0.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2952, in _initialize_master_working_set
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources-0.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 956, in subscribe
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources-0.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2952, in <lambda>
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources-0.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2515, in activate
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources-0.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2097, in declare_namespace
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources-0.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2047, in _handle_ns
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources-0.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2066, in _rebuild_mod_path
AttributeError: '_NamespacePath' object has no attribute 'sort'
```

I tried to uninstall and install pip3 but it didn't solve the problem. But even when I tried to check the version of pip3 I got the same message.

Comment: which command did you execute which caused the error?

Comment: [SO Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7446187/no-module-named-pkg-resources) which might be related

Answer (score 0):

By default, pip comes with python.

In Ubuntu, users may customized pip, as pip3 command was there to install Python3 packages, and pip was there to install Python2 packages.

Similarly, some users may customized, pip command to install Python3 packages and pip2 for Python2 packages.

Make a try with the below command:

```
python3 -m pip install tensorflow
```

When we use pip by specifying the python(version) -m (module option), we might get correct packages irrespective of pip2/pip3 mappings.

So the above command will install the correctly.